# Count unique values in column while also filtering on other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Bill Of Materials that I want to filter on several columns, then count the number of unique values in the Part Number column.  That count should update when I change the filter criteria in other columns.  How can I do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Does your filter provide unique results, or do you need to further reduce the results to a count of unique items?

Comment: I think some elaboration on the question would greatly help in addressing the problem.

Comment: You may be able to use a pivot table to do this if your filters are fairly basic.

Answer (score 5):

From [MrExcel.com](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/553903-count-unique-values-filtered-column.html):

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(A2),,1)),
    IF(A2:A10<>"",MATCH("~"&A2:A10,A2:A10&"",0))),ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(A2)+1),1))
```

The formula assumes that the data range is A2:A10. You will need to adjust the references for the cell A2 and the range A2:A10 to fit your data.

This is an array formula and must be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

Looking more closely at the expression, one sees that it depends upon the use of arrays in combination with four Excel functions. These are explained below. For purposes of illustration, the discussion will focus on the following example with a total of 9 values in cells A2:A10, with only 5 visible after filtering.

[image]

```
1.  MATCH("~" & A2:A10, A2:A10 & "", 0)
```

The `MATCH` function is normally used to look for a value in another range of values and, if the value is found, to return the row position where the matching value is found.

When an array is used as both the lookup value and the lookup range, `MATCH` returns an array that shows the row position of the first matching value, if any, for each of the values in the range.

If the range includes duplicate values, the same row position is returned for each duplicate value. Using the example data, the `MATCH` function would produce:

```
MATCH(A2:A10, A2:A10, 0)}

-->MATCH({11, 98, 67,  , 37, 67, 98, 56, 67},{11, 98, 67, ,37, 67, 98, 56, 67},0)

-->      { 1,  2 , 3, 4,  5,  3,  2,  8,  3}
```

With a little work, this result can be used to get a count of how many times each value occurs in the original array: For example, notice that the row position 3 for the value 67 shows up three times in the result array, corresponding to the three occurrences of that value in the input array.<sup>*</sup>

```
2.  SUBTOTAL(3, OFFSET(A2, ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(2),,1)
```

The particular difficulty in this question is how to distinguish values that appear in the filtered list from those that do not. The `SUBTOTAL` function applied to a range includes only visible rows in its result, but does not, even when entered as an array formula, provide information on whether the individual cells in its input range are visible or not.

However, the `OFFSET` function, as used here, returns an array of cells in a form such that `SUBTOTAL` produces an array result. [Credited](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/eee/eee001.txt) to Laurent Longre, this formulation yields an array of 1's for visible cells and 0's for hidden cells.

```
SUBTOTAL(3, OFFSET(A2, ROW(A2:A10) - ROW(A2), , 1))

--> SUBTOTAL(3, OFFSET(A2, {2, 3,..., 10} - {2}, , 1))

--> SUBTOTAL(3, OFFSET(A2, {0, 1,..., 8}, , 1))

--> SUBTOTAL(3, ({A2}, {A3},...,{A9}))

--> {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
```

With this result, it becomes possible to count in any subsequent calculations only the values in the range that are visible after filtering.<sup>**</sup>

```
3. FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(...)),IF(A2:A10<>"",MATCH(...))),
             ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(A2)+1)
```

The `FREQUENCY` function takes two arguments, an array of data values and a *bin* array, and returns an array that shows how many of the values in the range fell within each bin. For example, if the values in the bin range were (1.5, 2.5, 3.5), `FREQUENCY` would return a count of those data values that were less than or equal to 1.5, greater than 1.5 and less than or equal to 2.5, etc.

In the formula, the data array is expressed through a combination of IF statements and the  `SUBTOTAL/OFFSET` and `MATCH` expressions. What this really boils down to is an element-by-element ANDing of the arrays produced by those expressions.

```
SUBTOTAL/OFFSET ARRAY:  {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}  [visible vs. hidden]
MATCH ARRAY:            {1, 2, 3, F, 5, 3, 2, 8, 3}  [row position of 1st match]

RESULT ARRAY:           {F, 2, 3, F, F, F, 2, 8, 3}  [row position of 1st match        
                                                      in visible cells]
'F' = FALSE
```

The bin array produced by the expression `ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(A2)+1` is simply the values 1 through 9, corresponding to the possible row positions in the range A2:10.

```
BIN ARRAY:        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} 

FREQUENCIES:      {0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}
```

The frequencies jibe with the 2 times the value 98 shows in the filtered range, the 2 times 67 shows, and the 1 time 56 shows.

Since the goal is to count the number of distinct values in the filtered range, the final enclosing `IF` - `IF(FREQUENCY(...), 1)` - converts the non-zero values in the frequency array into 1's:

```
DISTINCT VALUES ARRAY:  {F, 1, 1, F, F, F, F, 1, 0}
```

Summing this array producing the final answer of 3 for this example.

<sup>*</sup>*The tilde (~) in the `MATCH` expression is included to escape characters such as '+' and '>' that would produce an error value if they were the first character in the values being matched (because Excel would treat them as operators rather than characters).*

<sup>**</sup>*The first argument to the `SUBTOTAL` function, the value 3, tells the function to return a count of the visible cells. The value most often seen, 9, produces the sum of the visible cells.*

Comment: I'm curious and like to understand the formula. Can you please elaborate it further?

Comment: See my edited answer, @nixda.

Comment: +1 Well done. This is a great answer and I learned a lot. This deserves more upvotes